# Documentation Generator for LaTeX

Tags: documentation, tex-general

Is there [Documentation Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Documentation_generator) for LaTeX like *Javadoc* for Java or *Doxygen* for C++?

Especially when defining macros or environments for LaTeX-files throughout a big project it would be useful for the team to have a nice documentation at best auto generated from commentary in the LaTeX-file.

Comment: Start here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming#Tools

Comment: Something like `docstrip`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer DocStrip is for getting the code out of commented sources: you are probably thinking of `doc`, `ltxdoc`, _etc._

Comment: @JosephWright: Yes, that's right. I meant `doc` or `ltxdoc` of course.

Comment: Perhaps something like [texinfo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texinfo)?

Comment: I was wondering the same. The attraction of things like Doxygen or Javadoc over `doc` and `ltxdoc` is that the intended use of a macro could be specified in a way that can be used by the computer and not only as human-only readable prose. Such info could for example be used by IDEs to extract templates and snippets for custom macros from their code

Answer (score 3):

The LaTeX Project have developed a series of tools to help documenting (La)TeX code: this is hardly surprising given the fact hat LaTeX itself is a large and complex piece of software.  The combination of various pieces of the 'jigsaw' leads to a file format known as `.dtx` ('documented (La)TeX source' or something like that). This format combines the ability to extract code from the source using DocStrip with mark-up tools for creating documentation using the `doc` package. I've [written about the format before](http://www.texdev.net/2009/10/05/the-dtx-format/) and provided a [starting point for creating an 'all in one' `.dtx`](http://www.texdev.net/2009/10/06/a-model-dtx-file/). A minimal-ise version might look something like

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
% 
% \section{The documentation}
% 
% \DescribeMacro{\examplemacro}
%   Some text about an example macro called \cs{examplemacro}, which
%   might have an optional argument \oarg{arg1} and mandatory one
%   \marg{arg2}. 
%
% \section{The code}
%
% Start the DocStrip guard for extracting the code.
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*package>
%    \end{macrocode}
%    
% \begin{macro}{\examplemacro}
%   Something about the implementation here, perhaps.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand*\examplemacro[2][]{%
  Some code here, probably
}
%    \end{macrocode}
%\end{macro} 
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%</package>
%    \end{macrocode}
```

where I've not provided the `.ins` file necessary to extract the code from the source, just the necessary set up to typeset some comments.

This format is used a lot by LaTeX package authors, so there are many variations on the standard set up on CTAN.