# Is there a Latex based documentation generator?

Tags: pandoc

The documentation generators that I know of either use HTML, Markdown(Pandoc), Restructured text (Sphinx), etc. I have not come across a pure latex-based one yet. The closest ones I know of is tex4ht.

Comment: Take a look here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/202616/6880 . I use to document a lot of my codes in Python but I recently decided to stop it such as to separate the documentation for users from the one for developers. I think that this is the reason why most of the documentations for LaTeX packages isn't user-friendly.

Comment: Yes, TeX4ht can generate documentation from LaTeX, see the [work in progress documentation](https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/tex4ht-doc.html) that is automatically generated using Github Actions from [this repository](https://github.com/michal-h21/tex4ht-doc). I use this [Github Action method](https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht-action) for all my recent projects, because Markdown is just too frustrating for me.

Comment: I'm not sure what a "documentation generator" is. Some years ago I wrote the `docmfp` package which enabled you to provide both code (e.g. Java, C, or other languages) to be output in one file and the documentation in LaTeX form to be output in a `.tex` for processing via LaTeX.